# Find the period of $\sin(\pi x)-\sin(2\pi x)+\sin(5\pi x)$?

Tags: periodic-functions

The period of $\sin(x)$ is $2\pi$. Thus the period of $\sin(\pi x)$ will become $T_1=2$, similarly the period of $\sin(2\pi x)$ is $T_2=1$ and for $\sin(5\pi x)$, the period is $T_3=\frac{2}{5}$.

To find the period of $\sin(\pi x)-\sin(2\pi x)+\sin(5\pi x)$, we can have
$$\frac{T_1}{T_{2}}=\frac{2}{1}\Rightarrow \,\, T^*=T_1=2T_2=2$$
Now, We can also have
$$\frac{T^*}{T_{3}}=\frac{2}{\frac{2}{5}}\Rightarrow \,\, T=2T^*=10T_3=4$$

So the period is 2. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
(T_1,T_2,T_3)=\left(\tfrac{10}5,\tfrac55,\tfrac25\right)
$$
where $\operatorname{LCM}(10,5,2)=10$ (least common multiple). Thus the minimal common integer multiple where those fractions coincide must be
$$
\frac{10}5=2\cdot \frac 55=5\cdot\frac25=2
$$
So your suggestion is correct.

Comment: The material from where I came up with the trigonometric functions says that the period is 10.

Comment: @MMM: That must be an error.

Comment: Is this has to do with the interval $(0,5)$ of study? Please check page E-2 - 22 of this document. http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-PDE%20pt2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right, since $2$ divided by $\frac{1}{3}$ is an integer, as well as the $1$. You can have a check by plotting

[The image of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3OOA.png)